# Segmentation Fault Loop C99

Tags: c, arrays, loops, segmentation-fault, quicksort

This code is a part of a much larger program. There is a `main` function within the code and it runs fine, sorry if its messy. Within the function `Quick_mode_time` in the second `while` loop I get a segmentation error, and I dont understand how I'm messing the array up to cause this. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very happy!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define timing_start() start = clock();
#define timing_end(f) msec = (double)(clock()-start) * 1000000.0 /CLOCKS_PER_SEC; \
    printf("Calling "#f " takes %10.2f microseconds!\n", msec);

void Quick_mode_time()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int end=500,final=5000;
    int a[end],beginning=0;
    double t1,t2,t_tot;
    printf("***************COMPARISON***************\n");

    printf("                quicksort       bubblesort      (in microseconds)\n");
    while(end!=final){

        while(beginning<end)
        {
            a[beginning]=rand()%end;  // <--- This causes a segmentation fault
            beginning++;
        }
        printf("N=%d",end);

        t1=clock();
        quicksort_time(a,0,end);

        t2=clock();
        t_tot= (double)(t2-t1)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("\t%7.3f\t", t_tot);
        end+=500;
    }
}

void quicksort_time(int x[],int first,int last){
    int pivot,j,temp,i;
    // The Quick Sorting algorithim is below!
    if(first<last){
        pivot=first;
        i=first;
        j=last;

        while(i<j){
            while(x[i]<=x[pivot]&&i<last)
                i++;
            while(x[j]>x[pivot])
                j--;
            if(i<j){
                temp=x[i];
                x[i]=x[j];
                x[j]=temp;
            }
        }

        temp=x[pivot];
        x[pivot]=x[j];
        x[j]=temp;
        quicksort_time(x,first,j-1);
        quicksort_time(x,j+1,last);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to determine which line is failing?

Comment: There's a comment in the code that says where the segfault occurs. What OP doesn't seem to know is that the array `a[end]` doesn't increase in size as `end` is increased.

Comment: `end+1-end` is `1`. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: I just changed it, it doesnt do anything nor should it i think because its just the range of numbers im placing into the array not doing anything with accessing memory locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
int a[end]
```

creates an array of 500 ints (end is set to 500 in the line before)

This line

```
a[beginning]=rand()%(end+1-end)+end;
```

writes to `a[beginning]` which is OK as long as `beginning` is less than 500.

This seems to be checked by this line just above:

```
while(beginning<end)
```

but later on in your code, you have:

```
end+=500;
```

so suddenly, end can be > 500, which means beginning can be > 500. Which means you write outside your array boundaries.

One fix would be to change your declaration so that `a` is big enough:

```
int a[final]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `while` loop never exits because you never modify the values of `end` or `final`.

Comment: they are modified at the end before the last bracket where i modify end+=500